# How do I return data via IEnumerable<ExchangeRate> function

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

I have a function GetExchangeRates which needs to return IEnumerable. I dont know how to do that. I can only write the result in the console and return `Null`. The `ExchangeRate` is a class with SourceCurrency/TargetCurrency=Value with only getters(immutable) and a constructor, returning `tostring() {SourceCurrency}/{TargetCurrency}={Value}"`;
And the main program class creates new[] set of currencies as `IEnum`. In the main I construct it and call:

```
var provider = new ExchangeRateProvider();
var rates = provider.GetExchangeRates(currencies)
```

And then just loop over rates and print it out. How do I pass the logic in the source code to the Main function properly?

```
public IEnumerable<ExchangeRate> GetExchangeRates(IEnumerable<Currency> currencies)
        {
            var xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmldoc.Load(@"http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml");

            XmlNodeList nodes = xmldoc.SelectNodes("//*[@currency]");

            if (nodes != null)
            {
                foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
                {
                    var rate = new ExchangeRate()
                    {
                        SourceCurrency = new Currency("EUR"),
                        TargetCurrency = new Currency(node.Attributes["currency"].Value),
                        Value = (Decimal.Parse(node.Attributes["rate"].Value, NumberStyles.Any,
                            new CultureInfo("en-Us")))
                    };
                    Console.WriteLine(rate);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `yield return` keyword here. For example,

```
yield return rate;
```

Complete Code

```
public IEnumerable<ExchangeRate> GetExchangeRates(IEnumerable<Currency> currencies)
{
            var xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmldoc.Load(@"http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml");

            XmlNodeList nodes = xmldoc.SelectNodes("//*[@currency]");

            if (nodes != null)
            {
                foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
                {
                    var rate = new ExchangeRate()
                    {
                        SourceCurrency = new Currency("EUR"),
                        TargetCurrency = new Currency(node.Attributes["currency"].Value),
                        Value = (Decimal.Parse(node.Attributes["rate"].Value, NumberStyles.Any,
                            new CultureInfo("en-Us")))
                    };
                    // ADDED YIELD RETURN  
                    yield return rate;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

The yield return keyword would return each element one at a time.You can read more on Yield keyword [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield)

Comment: Thank you! I forgot on yield. That basically fixed all my program.

Comment: @Azm Glad to help you. Kindly mark it answer if it helped to resolve your issue

Comment: How would I go about it if the ExchangeRate class had only getters?

Comment: @Azm In that case, you might have to exposure Constructor that accepts SourceCurrent,TargetCurrent, and Value. The properties would be then assigned with the constructor.

Comment: Yep, for some reason it did not work when I tried first time. Its all good now. Thanks.